# Convert date string in excel to date object in python

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

I have a date in excel which is given in: `dd mmm yy` format i.e.,

> 29 Jun 18

How do I convert this string into a date object?

I get the error:

> ```
> time data '13 Jul 18' does not match format '%d %m %Y'
> ```

when I try

```
datetime.strptime(input, '%d %m %Y')
```

What should the correct date format be?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Since the year in your excell is only two digits (i.e., 18 and not 2018) you need to use `%y` instead of `%Y` in your format string:

```
datetime.strptime(input, '%d %b %y')
```

For example:

```
datetime.strptime( '13 Jul 18', '%d %b %y')
```

Results with:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 13, 0, 0)
```

See [this page](http://strftime.org/) for more information about date/time string format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python datetime module or you can use dateutil parser to parse the string date to valid datetime object. I'd go with `dateutil parser` as I don't have to define string format. Here is an example

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse("Thu Sep 25 10:36:28 BRST 2003")
```

Remember to install dateutil by `pip install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of strptime which follows the pattern:

```
datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```

example:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('19 Jul 2017', '%d %b %y')
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

- You would have to `import datetime` and `import xlrd`
- Use `xlrd` to open the excel workbook as

  `book = xlrd.open_workbook("Excel.xlsx")
  sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Worksheet")`
- Use this to convert

  `obj = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell(row,column).value, book.datemode))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("29 Jun 18", "%d %b %y").date()
```

Here you get a datetime.date object, I don't know if that's good enough for you. I recommend you to visit the [documentation on the module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your format is incorrect: %b is Locale's short month and %y is two digit year

```
import time
time.strptime('13 Jul 18', '%d %b %y')

time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=194, tm_isdst=-1)
```